# Plugin route to a prefixed controller

Tags: cakephp, plugins, controller, routes, naming

I'm creating a plugin for my application (using CakePHP 2.6.0) that allows users to login into a user area using the same model as for the admin area, so I'm trying to get the same type of URI scheme as the admin area e.g. `/admin/users/login` but then for `/special/users/login`. I have the following route in my plugin's Config/routes.php and added the 'special' prefix to the 'Routing.prefixes' configuration:

```
Router::connect('/special/:controller/:action', array(
    'special' => true,
    'prefix' => 'special',
    'plugin' => 'Special',
    'controller' => ':controller',
    'action' => ':action',
));
```

With above route and entering the following url `/special/users/login` it would make sense to me right now if Cake went for `Plugin/Controller/SpecialUsersController.php` (considering namespace conflicts with the main application's UsersController) but instead I get an error `Error: Create the class UsersController`.

Is there a built-in way for it to load a prefixed controller (without changing the url) based on the plugin? Or is there a better way to neatly extend my main application? Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a built-in way for it to work as I wanted to so I changed the way URL strings were parsed using a custom route class in my app's `Routing/Route/` folder:

```
App::uses('CakeRoute', 'Routing/Route');

/**
 * Plugin route will make sure plugin routes get
 * redirected to a prefixed controller.
 */
class PluginRoute extends CakeRoute {

    /**
     * Parses a string URL into an array.
     *
     * @param string $url The URL to parse
     * @return bool False on failure
     */
    public function parse($url) {
        $params = parent::parse($url);

        if($params && !empty($params['controller']) && !empty($params['plugin'])) {
            $params['controller'] = $params['plugin'] . ucfirst($params['controller']);
        }

        return $params;
    }

}
```

And then setting up my plugin routes as:

```
App::uses('PluginRoute', 'Routing/Route');

Router::connect('/special/:controller/:action', array(
    'special' => true,
    'prefix' => 'special',
    'plugin' => 'Special',
    'controller' => ':controller',
    'action' => ':action',
), array(
    'routeClass' => 'PluginRoute'
));
```

This resulted in `/special/users/login` creating the controller I wanted `Plugin/Controller/SpecialUsersController.php`, no side effects so far. Extending the main application's UsersController is a different story though.

Maybe someone else has use of this or knows a better solution?